# Why is my reputation wrong on data.stackexchange.com?

Tags: support, reputation, data-explorer

My current reputation on the top bar of Stack Overflow is 1850.

But if I execute
https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/657729/top-users-in-portugal

my entry appears in the results list having a reputation of 1821 (my ranking position is #195).

Why?

Comment: The data there is not updated in real time

Comment: Now I've got a strange phenomenon: My Reputation is 1848 on Stack overflow site; and 1850 in Meta Stack overflow site!

Comment: @sergiol: Meta reputation is copied from the main site once per hour, see [How does Meta Stack Overflow work?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/259917)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [data.stackexchange.com homepage](https://data.stackexchange.com/):

> Data updated Apr 9 at 6:44

and from the [help page](https://data.stackexchange.com/help):

> **How often is the Stack Exchange Data Explorer updated?**
> The data is updated early every Sunday morning around 3:00 UTC. The last update was Apr 9 at 6:44.

You gained more reputation since that time.